# develop vscode extension on remote host

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to create an `extension`. The catch is that I am doing this on a `server` to which I am connected with the [ssh extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh).

I am using [yo](https://vscode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensions/yocode/) for the boilerplate and I follow the basic steps [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) to create a hello world project.

When I launch the `debugger` with `F5`, a new `VS Code` instance on the remote `server` is launched, but the `extension` is not installed in that instance. I am also not able to execute the command.

As side-information, this is a `raspberry Pi`, so its `32 bit arm`.

So the question is, is this generally possible to develop `extensions` on a Remote Host and if so, could the issue be related to the architecture of the `Pi`?

Comment: don't look of the extension is installed, see if you can execute the command defined in the developed extension, and if the command executes the new version in case it is an update

Comment: I cannot. That is implied.

Comment: do you see the `console.log` statements, in the activation function, as used in the helloworld tutorial of VSC doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could probably delete this question, but I will answer instead, maybe one day someone has the same problem.

When running `yo code`, the generated manifest will mark the extension as compatible with the *latest* VS Code engine. This may or may not be the version that is actually installed on your system.

```json
"engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.56"
}
```

For this example, the version is `1.56`. When I check for the installed version I see its `1.55.2` though.

```
$ code -v
1.55.2
3c4e3df9e89829dce27b7b5c24508306b151f30d
arm
```

When setting the engine in the manifest to at max the version in your system, it works as described in my question above.
Logically, if the version is too high, the extension won't be installed in any workspace.

I found this page also helpful, for the topic in general -> https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/remote-extensions